# Calculate the Viswanath's constant (Random Fibonacci sequences)

Tags: random, recursion, constraint

How Can I calculate  first few digits of [Viswanath's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_Fibonacci_sequence)?

> Viswanath’s constant ≈ 1.1319882487943 is a real number whose nth power approximates the absolute value of the nth term of some random Fibonacci sequences.

```
a[0] = 0;
a[1] = 1;
a[n_] := a[n] = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]*a[n - 1] + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]*a[n - 2]
```

I have *MMA 12.1* with high-end PC but there is no answer even for $n=50000$

by definition Viswanath’s constant is a $n$ th root of $a[n]$

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, N[a[50000]^(1/50000), 10]]
```

Comment: [Viswanath's original paper](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-99-01145-X) gives an algorithm for evaluating his constant.

Comment: One of the links in the Wikipedia article is to  [OEIS sequence A078416](https://oeis.org/A078416) for the decimal digits which has several links including one to the original paper.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui Can I use "Cuda cores" for this recursion?

Comment: I don't know; you should do an experiment to see.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem arises because of the depth of recursion.  If you evaluate smaller values first, the depth of recursion is much less.

For example, using your definition of `a`, the following evaluates in under a second

```
Block[{n = 100 i}, Table[a[n], {i, 1, 500}]];
```

memoizing the value for `a[50000]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe even a better solution is not to memoize the values at all:

```
Timing[a0 = 0; a1 = 1; n = 10^5;
 Do[{a0, a1} = {a1, a1 + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]*a0}, {n - 1}];
 N[Abs[a1]^(1/n), 10]]
(*Out: {0.103201, 1.134360272}*)
```

But the convergence is slow.